# Test a controller with distinct body and querystring params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I'd like to test with RSpec a controller receiving this kind of request:

```
curl -X POST                                   \
  --data   "{\"same_key\": \"value_in_body\"}" \
  --header "same_key: value_in_header"         \
  "http://localhost:5000/articles/?same_key=value_in_querystring"
```

having:

- `same_key` in the body
- `same_key` in the header
- `same_key` in the querystring

and where:

- `request.request_parameters["same_key"]`: `"value_in_body"`
- `request.headers["same_key"]`: `"value_in_header"`
- `request.query_parameters["same_key"]`: `"value_in_querystring"`

I wrote this test:

```
RSpec.describe ArticlesController, type: :controller do
  describe '#create' do
    it 'creates an article' do
      post :post,
        as:      :json,
        params:  { same_key: 'value_in_body' },
        headers: { same_key: 'value_in_header' }

      expect(response).to have_http_status(:created)
    end
  end
end
```

So far, it would be good for the *body* param and the *header* param.

But how should we do to also send the *querystring* param?

Answer (score 1):

If you really need this kind of scenario, you have to use the Rails URI pattern instead of only specifying action name in the post statement,

```
post '/documents/create_new_doc', params: {same_key: 'value_in_body'}
```

Note: Get the exact URI pattern from **rake routes**

Comment: I know this. 
But then how can we do to not override the _body_ param (because both have the same key)?

Comment: Yeah, I got your point, because it's a post request. So, instead of using action name you can use the RUI pattern like 'sessions/' that you can get it from rake routes.

Comment: This pattern is used by RSpec's request tests. 
In the context of a RSpec's controller test, the first argument must be an action, not a path.

Comment: @CirusPolis: Have you tried by Rails URI pattern? Actually Rails RSpec should allow url patten as well.

Comment: Yes. 
Unfortumally, it is working for request spec (https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec), but not for controller specs (https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/controller-specs).

Answer (score 0):

You actually can't have both `request.query_parameters` and `request.request_parameters` at the same time from either `post` or `get` functions in RSpec Controller tests or Request tests. This other Stack Overflow answer explains that RSpec only ever sets one or the other: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36715875/2479282

The solution (posed by that other answer) is to use IntegrationTests instead, a'la:

```rb
class CollectionsTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test 'foo' do
    post collections_path, { collection: { name: 'New Collection' } }, 
                           { "QUERY_STRING" => "api_key=my_api_key" }

    # this proves that the parameters are recognized separately in the controller
    # (you can test this in you controller as well as here in the test):
    puts request.POST.inspect
    # => {"collection"=>{"name"=>"New Collection"}}
    puts request.GET.inspect
    # => {"api_key"=>"my_api_key"}
  end
end
```